# Universal method for solving curves when given curvature and torsion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves

For planar case, given curvature $\kappa$, we can take $x'(s)=cos \theta(s), y'(s)=sin \theta(s)$ and get $\theta(s)=\int \kappa(s)ds$, then solve two "independent" ODE (that is, only an integral) to get the curve.

However, for spatial case, I don't know whether there is a universal method to solve curves when given curvature and torsion.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general space curve is given by a fourth order differential equation in three dimensions:

> $$\boldsymbol{x}^{(4)}-
>    \left( \frac{2\kappa'}{\kappa}+\frac{\tau'}{\tau} \right) \boldsymbol{x}'''+
>    \left(
>     \kappa^{2}+\tau^{2}+
>      \frac{2\kappa'^{2}-\kappa \kappa''}{\kappa^{2}}+
>    \frac{\kappa' \tau'}{\kappa \tau}
>    \right) \boldsymbol{x}''+
>   \kappa^{2}\left( \frac{\kappa'}{\kappa}-\frac{\tau'}{\tau} \right) \boldsymbol{x}'=
>   \mathbf{0}$$

which is only solvable for some special cases.