# How to find the coordinates of a cylindrical helix whose curvature and torsion are given?

Tags: differential-geometry

It's given in the question that $\kappa=\tau=1/s$.

By Serret-Frenet Formulae I know that

$\vec{r\prime}=\frac{1}{s}\hat{n}$ and $\vec{r\prime\prime}=\frac{-1}{s^2}\hat{n}+\frac{1}{s}(\frac{1}{s}\hat{b}-\frac{1}{s}\hat{t})=\frac{-1}{s^2}\hat{n}+\frac{1}{s^2}\hat{b}-\frac{1}{s^2}\hat{t}$

$\hat{t},\hat{n},\hat{b}$ are functions of s and their components are unknown. How can I go further to solve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be a conical helix, namely

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{r}(s) &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{6}} \, \cos (\sqrt{2}\, \ln s) \\[2pt]
    \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{6}} \, \sin (\sqrt{2}\, \ln s) \\[2pt]
    \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}}
  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  \kappa &= \frac{1}{s} \\[5pt]
  \tau &= \frac{1}{s}
\end{align*}

For more general case, see another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988916/parametric-form-of-conical-helix) and also the ODE for space curve [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947976/universal-method-for-solving-curves-when-given-curvature-and-torsion).